# How to stream camera via cvlc (rtsp) to multiple (vlc-)clients

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I have a usb-camera connected to a raspberry pi.

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=mp2v --v4l2-width 1280 --v4l2-height 720 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,acodec=mpga,fps=3}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8888/live.sdp}'
```

I can see the camera stream in vlc through accessing:
rtsp://[RPI-IP]:8888/live.sdp

but if i open vlc on a second machine and try to get it, the first one gets kicked out. Why and what needs to be configured to prevent that?

Comment: share full verbose logs

Comment: maybe your camera can only stream to one client